# Float not correct in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, floating-point, precision

I am entering '35444650.00' as a float into my MySQL and it keeps reformatting to 35444648.00, any help welcome...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Floats only have a certain level of precision, you may be going beyond how precise a float data type can be.  Try using a DOUBLE instead.

Answer (score 4):

A float has 6 digits of precision. Use a double to get 15 or switch to a numeric(x,y). If you're interested, check out the [storage requirements for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-requirements.html) for the different data types.

Answer (score 4):

The MySQL manual claims that `FLOAT, REAL, and DOUBLE PRECISION` fields stores values **as approximate** and `INTEGER, SMALLINT, DECIMAL, and NUMERIC` fields stores values **as exact**.

I think best bet to overcome this precision issue is to use decimal.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html

Answer (score 2):

A higher precision alternative to  float is `DOUBLE`. But looking at the example, I think the `DECIMAL` datatype might come in handy if the number of digits required after zero is small (around 2-4) and the number of digits before decimal is also small (around 10-12).

Answer (score 0):

You are going past the level of precision possible. You need to define the float with more precision, i.e. "FLOAT(10,5)" would mean a float that can have 10 digits total with up to five after the decimal point.